# The element type 'Future<void>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

```
builder: (context, state) {
          if(state.status == RecievingState.success && state.userData != null){
            return  Column(
            children: [  Vibration.vibrate(); //error
            ],)
            },
            }
```

as soon as the data is changed from API. I want the phone to vibrate within same page...

Comment: Can you include more about `vibrate` and what are you trying to do

Comment: i want to vibrate the phone from the bool of api.
api is fethched periodically in 1 sec interval. So if the bool changes i want to vibrate my phone.

Answer (score 1):

If you like vibrate every time the `if` condition get satisfied, you can do :

```dart
builder: (context, state) {
     if(state.status == RecievingState.success && state.userData != null){
        Vibration.vibrate();
        return  Column(
          children: [
```

You can add another `bool` to control the vibrate on the `build` method.

If you like to check the state, Use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

Comment: if(state.userData![index].hasPlanted == true)...[
    Vibration.vibrate(); //error
]

data is fetched from API but 
The element type 'Future<void>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Comment: `Vibration.vibrate();` will be before return column

Answer (score 0):

Column children should be widget only like this

```
Column(
children: <Widget>[
const Text('hello'),
const Text('world'),
] )
```

if you want to use vibrate please [refer](https://pub.dev/packages/vibration)

Comment: Column is fine there :), the issue with calling future method